# spring mvc: Could not resolve dynamic value in placeholder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**I am migrating project Struts1 to spring mvc.**

1. In struts errror handling done by message-resources in struts-config.xml

`<message-resources parameter=" resources.messages " />`
**message.properties**
`login.error.missingValue=Please supply a value for {0}.`
`login.error.missingValues=Please supply values for these fields: {0}`
**ActionClass**
`addError(request, new ActionError(MISSING_VALUE_ERROR, missing,new Integer(missingCount)));`
In second parameter user passing dynamic value like username/password.
**I tried below things in spring mvc...but not able to get dynamic value.**
spring-servlet.xml
`<context:property-placeholder location="/resources/messages.properties"/>`

@Controller

`@Value("${login.error.missingValue}")`
`private String MISSING_VALUE_ERROR`
I am getting below output in spring.
Please supply a value for {0}.
I want to replace {0} with dynamic value like...username/password etc.
Please help he me here how can I do in Spring MVC?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both spring and struts provide mechanisms for error message handling and rendering them to the client browser.

Both do the same thing but in other ways, but  with different purposes.
If you're using struts to represent your frontend then you should use the struts message resource way to render the error messages back to the client.

Regarding your error and question:

You autowired a value defined as a property resource, handled by spring property placeholder, which expects at startup to have a value present (imagine using a plain properties file with a missing value vs a message resource)

In order to fix your error above, you need to comply with the default spring message source lookup ( as your autowired values is not a property, it's a message).

**For this to work you have to define the following**:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and afterwards autowire the MessageSource and get the dynamic value from there.

You can find more examples [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/resolving-text-messages-in-spring-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/)